# Draw border around constant regions of image

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation

I would like to ask that is it possible to draw borderline - contour - around those cells (pixels) which are neighboring and contains the same value.

An example by hand:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to treat it as an image and to use edgedetect:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI4S4.png"];
ImageMultiply[ColorNegate[EdgeDetect[img, 1, 0.1]], img]
```

[image]