# How to unite polygons of the same color into a single polygon?

Tags: computational-geometry

Let a partition of a planar polygon into colored polygons be given, i.e. something similar to
[image]

We know the coordinates of the vertices and the color of each part, e. g. in such a way

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Red,  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, 
    {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 0}}], 
 EdgeForm[Black], Green,    Polygon[{{0, 2}, {0, 6}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}, {2, 4}, 
    {2, 5}, {1, 5}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}}], 
 EdgeForm[Black], Blue, Polygon[{{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {2, 3}}], 
 EdgeForm[Black], Red, Polygon[{{3, 2}, {3, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 2}}],
 EdgeForm[Black], Green, Polygon[{{2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {3, 1}}], 
 EdgeForm[Black], Green, Polygon[{{4, 0}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

How to write a Mathematica program which unites the polygons having a joint edge and  the same color into a single  polygon with the simply-connected interior, not a polygonial figure (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Polygon) and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon))?
For the above partition we have to obtain two green polygons, one red polygon, one yellow polygon,
one blue polygon, and one violet polygon.

Addition.
The following result in green is not a polygon so is not allowed:

[image]

Comment: can you post the code that produced the picture?

Comment: @kglr: Here is an example `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Red, 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {4,
      0}}], EdgeForm[Black], Green, 
  Polygon[{{0, 2}, {0, 6}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 5}, {1,
      3}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}}], EdgeForm[Black], Blue, 
  Polygon[{{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {2, 3}}], EdgeForm[Black], Red, 
  Polygon[{{3, 2}, {3, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 2}}], EdgeForm[Black], Green, 
  Polygon[{{2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {3, 1}}], EdgeForm[Black], Green, 
  Polygon[{{4, 0}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {5, 0}}]}]`.

Comment: @kglr: Also see [that question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235861/how-to-draw-borders-around-tiles-of-the-same-color).

Comment: user64494, i suggest you add the example in your comment in your post. Maybe also clarify how you want to treat the cases where a subset of polygons with a common color form a polygon with a hole.

Comment: @kglr: I listened to you and added the example and the definition.  I will be absent at the page during several hours.

Comment: Perhaps a `RelationGraph` with the criterion that two polygons are connected if their colours are the same AND their `RegionUnion` is a `SimplePolygonQ`, then take connected components of that graph. Unfortunately I cannot explore this idea in Mathematica because `RegionUnion` is too buggy and sometimes crashes the kernel for certain polygon arrangements.

Answer (score 5):

#### Input examples

First a slightly modified form of the example input from OP:

```
gr1 = Graphics[SequenceReplace[#, p : {_RGBColor, _Polygon} :> p] & @
   {EdgeForm[ Black], Red, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, 
       {4, 2}, {4, 0}}], 
  EdgeForm[Black], Green, Polygon[{{0, 2}, {0, 6}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, 
       {1, 5}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}}], 
  EdgeForm[Black], Blue, Polygon[{{1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {2, 3}}],
  EdgeForm[Black], Red,  Polygon[{{3, 2}, {3, 6}, {5, 6}, {5, 2}}], 
  EdgeForm[Black], Green, Polygon[{{2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {3, 1}}]}];
```

Additional examples where the combined regions have no holes (`gr2`) , a single hole (`gr3`)  and multiple holes (`gr4`):

```
SeedRandom[1]
polygons = MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}]], {2, "Interior"}];

{gr2, gr3} = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}], 
      MapIndexed[Function[{x, y}, Table[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, Length@#}}]@y[[1]], 
          polygons[[i]]}, {i, x}]], #]}] & /@ 
       {{{2, 5, 10}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}, {1, 7}, {9}}, 
       {{5, 10, 9, 7, 3}, {6}, {4, 8}, {2, 1}}};

SeedRandom[77]
gr4 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], {RandomChoice[{2, 1} -> {Red, Blue}], #}} & /@ 
    MeshPrimitives[MengerMesh[2], 2]];

Grid[{Style[#, 24] & /@ {"gr1", "gr2", "gr3", "gr4"}, 
  Show[#, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ {gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4}}, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

#### Combined polygons allowed to have holes:

We group polygons by color and take the `RegionUnion` of each group of polygons and `RegionPlot` it with the color associated with the group:

```
ClearAll[bdR, combinePolygonsByColorHolesAllowed]

bdR = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion @@ #, 
    MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> #2, 1 -> Directive[Thick, Gray]}] &;

combinePolygonsByColorHolesAllowed = Show[Values[
     GroupBy[Cases[#[[1]], {_RGBColor, _Polygon}, All], First, 
      Module[{color = #[[1, 1]], polys = #[[All, 2]]}, 
        bdR[polys, color]] &]], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic] &;

Grid[{Style[#, 24] & /@ {"gr1", "gr2", "gr3", "gr4"}, 
    Show[#, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ #, 
    Show[#, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ combinePolygonsByColorHolesAllowed /@ #}, 
   Dividers -> All] &@{gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4}
```

[image]

#### Combined polygons cannot have holes:

If holes are not allowed, we need to identify the holes in the region formed by the group of polygons. For this purpose, we `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` the `RegionUnion` of the polygon group and use the (undocumented) function `` Region`Mesh`FindMeshRegionHoles `` which returns `None` if the mesh region does not have any holes and, if it does, a point for each of the holes. For each hole `h`, we find the polygons that lie on the line from a point in `h` to nearest point on the outer boundary (obtained using `ConnectedMeshComponents`) and `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` the `RegionUnion` of resulting partition of the polygon group.

```
ClearAll[findHoles, combinePolygonsByColorNoHoles]

findHoles = Region`Mesh`FindMeshRegionHoles[
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion @@ #]] &;

combinePolygonsByColorNoHoles = Show[Values[
     GroupBy[Cases[#[[1]], {_RGBColor, _Polygon}, All], First, 
      Module[{color = #[[1, 1]], polys = #[[All, 2]], 
         bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion @@ #[[All, 2]]], 
         outerboundary,  lines, partition},
        If[findHoles[polys] === None, bdR[polys, color], 
         outerboundary =  First@ConnectedMeshComponents[
            DiscretizeGraphics[MeshPrimitives[bdr, {1, "Boundary"}]]];
         lines =  Rationalize[Line[{#, RegionNearest[outerboundary, #]}] & /@ 
            findHoles[polys], 10^-4]; 
         partition = {Complement[polys, ##], ##} & @@ 
           Table[Select[Rationalize[polys, 10^-4], 
             Head[RegionIntersection[#, ln]] === Line &], {ln , lines}]; 
         Show[bdR[First @ partition, color], 
          bdR[#, Lighter @ Lighter @ color] & /@ Rest[partition], 
          PlotRange -> All]]] &]],
     PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &;
```

Showing input graphics (first row), outputs from `combinePolygonsByColorHolesAllowed` (second row) and outputs from `combinePolygonsByColorNoHoles` (third row):

```
Grid[{Style[#, 24] & /@ {"gr1", "gr2", "gr3", "gr4"}, 
    Show[#, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ #, 
    Show[#, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ combinePolygonsByColorHolesAllowed /@ #, 
    Show[#, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ combinePolygonsByColorNoHoles /@ #}, 
 Dividers -> All] & @ {gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4}
```

[image]

Focusing on the red polygons in `gr4`:

```
gr4a = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Cases[gr4[[1]], {Red, _}, All]}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium];
gr4b = Replace[combinePolygonsByColorHolesAllowed[gr4], 
  {Directive[{___, Blue, ___}], _} -> {}, All];
gr4c = Replace[combinePolygonsByColorNoHoles[gr4],
  {Directive[{___, Blue | Lighter[Lighter@Blue], ___}], _} -> {}, All];

Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> 250] & /@ {gr4, gr4a, gr4b, gr4c}]
```

[image]

**Note:** We can also use `RegionPlot` instead of `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` above; that is, we can replace the function `rdF` above with `rP`:

```
rP = RegionPlot[RegionUnion @@ #, PlotPoints -> 90, 
    MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotStyle -> #2, BoundaryStyle -> Thick] &;
```

The 2D primitives produced by the functions above are `FilledCurve`s if we use `rdF`; they are `Polygon`s if we use `rP`.

Comment: +1. Thank you for your interest to the question and your work. The results of gr1 and gr4 are not final and can be extended.

Comment: @user64494, thanks for the upvote. I was about to delete this answer because removing  multiple holes requires a more complicated approach. Good question btw. I will post an update if I find a clean way to handle multiple holes.

Comment: The result of gr1 in "Combined polygons cannot have holes" is not final yet: two green polygons can be combined.

Comment: @user64494, if you combine the two green pieces the resulting shape will have a hole, no?

Comment: No, think of the horizontal jont edge. Removing it, one obtains a polygon without holes and with the simply-connected interior. Of course, that polygon is not simple.

Comment: @user64494, oh i (mis)interpreted "unite polygons" and "hole".

Comment: @kglr, wow, cool stuff. How would you go about merging 3d polygons, like, say, two 3d triagles with common edge? `tr1 = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 3, 0}},Triangle[{1, 2, 3}]]; tr2 = MeshRegion[{{2, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 3, 0}},Triangle[{1, 2, 3}]];`